# Embedded Jetty java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to write a small embedded Jetty program for an app that is normally deployed to Tomcat. My app appears to initialize fine but then the Jetty server start throws an error related to logging. I have a log4j.properties file in my src directory and am including log4j and slf4j-log4j12 as Maven dependencies. Any idea where I've erred?

Thanks!

```
WARN - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@6b0e9064: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/log/Log
    at com.sun.org.apache.commons.logging.JettyLog.<init>(JettyLog.java:36)
    at com.sun.org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<clinit>(JspServlet.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ServletContextHandler.java:1164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:810)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at com.foo.rscontrolcenter.ControlCenter.main(ControlCenter.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Here is my program:

```java
public class ControlCenter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server( 8080 );
        WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext("ControlCenter/Website/", "/controlcenter");
        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();

        handlerCollection.addHandler(root);

        server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
        server.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Set the classpath for where the `.class`es are. `java -cp bin com.path.ControlCenter` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose the wrong JspServlet implementation.

It is looking for `org.mortbay.jetty` based classes, that's for Old Jetty 6 and earlier.

**The Example Project**

Look at the `jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp` example on github for a working example of embedded jetty + jsp support.

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp

Pay attention to:

- The [meta-dependency for jetty-jsp](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/pom.xml#L23-L34) in /pom.xml
- The [configuration for JavaC use with Jsp](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java#L106-L107) in org.eclipse.jetty.demo.Main
- The [setup of JspServlet](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java#L127-L138) in org.eclipse.jetty.demo.Main
- The [setup of Classloaders](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/Main.java#L120-L125) in org.eclipse.jetty.demo.Main

**The Dependencies**

Here's the dependency tree in use by that example project

```
[embedded-jetty-jsp]$ mvn dependency:tree
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building embedded-jetty-jsp 1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ embedded-jetty-jsp ---
[INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.demo:embedded-jetty-jsp:jar:1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |           +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] |           \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:pom:9.1.0.v20131115:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain:jetty-schemas:jar:3.1.M0:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.0.v201105211821:compile
[INFO]    +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish:jar:1.2.0.v201112081803:compile
[INFO]    \- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.528s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 05 11:03:49 MST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/484M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```